# How to reduce gaps between vuetify elements?

Tags: vuetify.js

Please help me reducing gaps between vuetify elements like v-select, v-btn, v-textfield, and gaps between data-table cells. I have tried class="ma-0 pa-0" .[image: example]

Comment: If you use `ma-0` and `pa-0` there will be more space to reduce anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having similar issues with spacing between `v-text-field`. 
For me the fix to get the text fields pressed together was to set `hide-details`, so [it hides hints/validation errors](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#text-field).

```
<v-text-field dark hide-details value="Example"></v-text-field>
```